# $\prod_{i: \text{prime}}\left(1-\frac{1}{i^2}\right) = \frac{6}{{\pi}^2}$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I was reading Chebychev's Theorem about the probability of a fraction to be irreducible and I came accross this evaluation $$\prod_{i: \text{ prime}}\left(1-\frac{1}{i^2}\right) = \frac{6}{{\pi}^2}$$ I wonder how can I prove this.

Any hint?

Comment: As far as I can see, it is not something easy, at least for my level...and I feel a bit releaved know that I could not proove it. To be honest my first thought was the Wallis equality for pi, but of course it did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer to [Euler's product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product)

$$\prod_{p} (1-p^{-s})^{-1} = \prod_{p} \Big(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p^{-ns}\Big) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{s}} = \zeta(s)$$

and to

[Different methods to compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$ (Basel problem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2-basel-pro).

Comment: Of course, proving that $\zeta(2) = \pi^2/6$ is not exactly a trivial matter.

Comment: For that https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2-basel-pro